# Php opens up a whole bunch of windows

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script that I got from another guy and for some reason the login function does not work unless it opens up in a new window. (??? no idea why but that's just how it is) Anyways when I execute the open up window javascript from my PHP file, it opens up a whole bunch of windows. I figured that it was somehow looping, so I put the javascript function inside of a for loop that should only execute once. When I click my button, it opens up windows continously until I feverishly close them all and it stops.

Here is the code that seems to be the issue:

```
    if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])==USRFILE && (isset($_REQUEST['usr']) || isset($_REQUEST['susr']) || isset($_GET['mp']) || isset($_REQUEST['rc']))) 
  {
      if(ISAJAX === 0) include(USRTEMPL.'head.php');        // if not Ajax request, include head.php (from USRTEMPL)
      include(USRINCLS.'class.UsersReg.php');        // include the class for Register (used also for Recovery data)

      ob_start();           // start storing output in buffer

      // if 'susr'=Register, create objet of UsersReg (for Register)
      // if 'rc' or 'mp' (for Recover-Confirma), uses UsersRecov class
      // if 'usr', create object of UserPage class (for user page data)
      if(isset($_REQUEST['susr']) && $_REQUEST['susr']==$lsite['users_logform']['register']) {
        $objRe = new UsersReg($mysql);
        echo $objRe->result;
        for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x=2) 
        {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?susr=Register');</script>";
        }
      }
      else if(isset($_REQUEST['rc']) || isset($_GET['mp'])) {
        include(USRINCLS.'class.UsersRecov.php'); //account recovery
        $objRe = new UsersRecov($mysql);
            for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x=2) 
            {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?rc=Recover');</script>";
        }
      }
```

Specifically this section:

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['susr']) && $_REQUEST['susr']==$lsite['users_logform']['register']) {
    $objRe = new UsersReg($mysql);
    echo $objRe->result;
    for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x=2) 
    {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?susr=Register');</script>";
    }
```

I tried looking up javascript opening up many windows but didn't find anything noteworthy. Same goes when I looked up php opening up a whole bunch of windows. It really makes no sense why it is looking, because it was looping before I put the for loop in. I put in the for loop to stop it, and it still loops.

Comment: `for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x=2)` why would you ever do that?

Comment: QUESTION: does this code live or get executed on users.php? if so, then you have an infinite loop. goto page users.php > if `$_REQUEST['susr'] == 'Register'` > open window to users.php > if `$_REQUEST['susr'] == 'Register'` > open window to users.php > etc....

Comment: A loop that only executes once is exactly the same as just putting the code there with no loop.

Comment: Worth noting that php can't open windows. It can only output JS that opens windows. So, what is the HTML/JS  output of this code?

Comment: I recommend you checkout Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code lives on or gets executed from `users.php` then that is your problem, because you would have an infinite loop.

The first line **only** runs this code on the users.php page (or it seems that way based on the constant name). The code goes on to say:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['susr']) && $_REQUEST['susr']==$lsite['users_logform']['register']) {
```

I'm assuming that `$lsite['users_logform']['register'] == 'Register'`. Thus, when you visit users.php, this code runs. If the `$_REQUEST['susr'] == 'Register'` (because of the first page load that opened a new window to a url that matches `users.php?susr=Regsiter`), then you are instructing it to open ANOTHER instance of the page again, here:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['susr']) && $_REQUEST['susr']==$lsite['users_logform']['register']) {
  $objRe = new UsersReg($mysql);
  echo $objRe->result;
  for($x = 0; $x < 1; $x=2) 
  {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?susr=Register');</script>";
  }
}
```

IMO, you need to tell the second request to `users.php` (generated by your javascript bit) that it is from javascript. Then ignore your entire code block if it is from javascript. Something like this should work:

```
if ( !isset($_GET['from_js']) && basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])==USRFILE && ( isset($_REQUEST['usr']) || isset($_REQUEST['susr']) || isset($_GET['mp']) || isset($_REQUEST['rc']) ) ) 
{
  if(ISAJAX === 0) include(USRTEMPL.'head.php');        // if not Ajax request, include head.php (from USRTEMPL)
  include(USRINCLS.'class.UsersReg.php');        // include the class for Register (used also for Recovery data)

  ob_start();           // start storing output in buffer

  // if 'susr'=Register, create objet of UsersReg (for Register)
  // if 'rc' or 'mp' (for Recover-Confirma), uses UsersRecov class
  // if 'usr', create object of UserPage class (for user page data)
  if(isset($_REQUEST['susr']) && $_REQUEST['susr']==$lsite['users_logform']['register']) {
    $objRe = new UsersReg($mysql);
    echo $objRe->result;
    // there is no reason for the for loop. totally pointless
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?susr=Register&from_js=1');</script>";
  }
  else if(isset($_REQUEST['rc']) || isset($_GET['mp'])) {
    include(USRINCLS.'class.UsersRecov.php'); //account recovery
    $objRe = new UsersRecov($mysql);
    // there is no reason for the for loop. totally pointless
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?rc=Recover&from_js=1');</script>";
  }
}
```

Ok. I changed the first line to include a check for the `$_GET['from_js']` variable. I removed the for loops, because they are totally pointless, since they only ever run once. To the urls that are opened in the new window, I added `&from_js=1`. With this, your code does not run on the subsequent new window openings. This will prevent the infinite popups.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.thelegendmaker.net/users.php?susr=Register');</script>";
```

to:

```
 header('Location: users.php?susr=Register');
```